# XPath to get element with maximum/minimum attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath

For this XML,

```
<MediaFiles>
  <MediaFile id="" bitrate="670" type="video/mp4">
    http://example.com/test.mp4
  </MediaFile>
  <MediaFile id="" bitrate="1800" type="video/mp4">
    http://example.com/test2.mp4
  </MediaFile>
  <MediaFile id="" bitrate="600" type="video/x-flv">
    http://example.com/test3.mp4
  </MediaFile>
  <MediaFile id="" bitrate="450" type="video/x-flv">
    http://example.com/test4.mp4
  </MediaFile>
</MediaFiles>
```

My question is how to get `Mediafile` with the highest `@bitrate` (in this case I should get `http://example.com/test2.mp4` as the `@bitrate` attribute is 1800 the highest).

For example, I'm able to get an array with the `Mediafiles`

```
/VAST/Ad/InLine/Creatives/Creative/Linear/MediaFiles/MediaFile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to use XPath to select the element with the maximum or minimum attribute values:

**Maximum**

```
//MediaFile[not(@bitrate < ../MediaFile/@bitrate)][1]
```

**Minimum**

```
//MediaFile[not(@bitrate > ../MediaFile/@bitrate)][1]
```

(Drop the trailing `[1]` if you want all `MediaFile` elements tied with a max/min `@bitrate` value.)